# Benchmarks and state-of-the-art methods for semantic segmentation of 3D meshes?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm wondering what benchmarks there exist for semantic segmentation of 3D meshes? I have already found "[A Benchmark for 3D Mesh Segmentation](http://segeval.cs.princeton.edu/)"; is this currently the only benchmark that exists for 3D mesh segmentation?

Also, is there some list of state-of-the-art methods for semantic segmentation of 3D meshes, like there is for [some](https://github.com/RedditSota/state-of-the-art-result-for-machine-learning-problems) [other](https://www.cityscapes-dataset.com/benchmarks/#scene-labeling-task) [benchmarks](https://dawn.cs.stanford.edu/benchmark/)?

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

Currently there seems to be a preference for using point clouds over raw meshes for 3d segmentation. They can use all the benchmarks below plus:

1. **S3DIS**
   URL: http://buildingparser.stanford.edu/dataset.html
2. **ScanNet**
   URL: http://www.scan-net.org/

The state of the art seems to be [11] closely followed by [10] and both use PointNet++ [12].

---

The one you are refering to is the common **PSB** (Princeton Segmentation Benchmark) dataset [1].
Other Important datasets used for 3D mesh segmentation are:

1. **COSEG** [2]

   - URL: http://irc.cs.sdu.edu.cn/~yunhai/public_html/ssl/ssd.htm
2. **ShapeNet** [3]

   - URL: https://www.shapenet.org/
3. Other from Princeton [4]

   - URL: http://shape.cs.princeton.edu/vkcorrs/papers_small/13_SIGGRAPH_CorrsTmplt.pdf
4. Other basen on subset of ShapeNet [5]

   - URL: https://cs.stanford.edu/~ericyi/project_page/part_annotation/

On the other hand, there seems to be no state-of-the-art page for 3D shape segmentation. But the papers I find most important are [6, 7, 8, 9], with 9 the state of the art.

---

*Refs*:

1. Chen et al: *A Benchmark for 3D Mesh Segmentation*, 2009
2. Wang et al: 
   *Active co-analysis of a set of shapes*, 2012
3. Kim et al: *Learning Part-based Templates from Large Collections of 3D Shapes*, 2013
4. Chang et al: *ShapeNet: An Information-Rich 3D Model Repository*, 2015
5. Yi et al: *A scalable active framework for region annotation in 3d shape collections*, 2016
6. Kalogerakis et al: *Learning 3D Mesh Segmentation and Labeling*, 2010
7. Guo et al: *3D Mesh Labeling via Deep Convolutional Neural Networks*, 2015
8. Kalogerakis et al: *3D Shape Segmentation with Projective Convolutional Networks*, 2017
9. Wang et al: *3D shape segmentation via shape fully convolutional networks*, 2018
10. Wang et al: *Associatively Segmenting Instances and Semantics in Point Clouds*, 2019
11. Yang et al: *Learning Object Bounding Boxes for 3D Instance Segmentation on Point Clouds*, 2019
12. Qi et al: *PointNet++: Deep Hierarchical Feature Learning on
    Point Sets in a Metric Space*, 2017